# Get Correct index in SimpleAdapter listview

Tags: android, simpleadapter

i have this Code for my Listview adapter,i am using SimpleAdapter ,it works fine but when i use the search textbox it returns the wrong index of the item
selected.
Please how do i get the correct index of the selected item ..

Thanks @ all

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index

                int songIndex = position; //returns position here

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter)PlayListActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `int songIndex = position;` is correct. What's exactly the issue ?

Comment: when using the listview search textbox,it brings out results,but clicking on a LIstitem will not get the corresponding index e.g i click the 6th it returns the 2nd, since i did not realy scroll the listview but searched it

Comment: Also implement view holder pattern

Comment: please explain what u mean clearly